# how to disable nginx mail for one of server blocks only?

Tags: nginx, sendmail, virtualhost, postfix-mta

I want to disable nginx mail for one of the server blocks (virtual hosts) on the server where a wordpress blog is running, so when the wordpress blog tries to send an email, the server won't send it. I searched over the Net for a while but I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: well nginx isn't what sends your mail, you should tag your question with `sendmail` and `postfix` if you use postfix

Comment: I don't want to disable the whole mail function. I want to disable it for one of nginx server blocks only.

Comment: Can you assign two public addresses to the host?

Comment: @andrzej-a-filip, no I only have 1 NIC.

Comment: Is switching to apache an option? AFAIK apache offers per running different virtual hosts as different OS users. It could allow to achieve what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the web server to Apache. I'm forced to use Nginx.

Comment: How do you serve PHP from nginx? I'm asking because nginx itself does not contain PHP interpreter.

Comment: I use php-fpm package on centos 5.9.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think nginx play any role when the wordpress send an email here. Why don't disable all email notifications from wordpress?

Where is a thread on the wordpress phorum dealing with the issue:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/turn-off-email-notifications

Comment: It's not my own site. I'm hosting someone else's site, and I don't want them to be able to send emails. In the other hand I don't want other sites on the same server to be effected.

Comment: Do they have a particular email or some header you can verify? If yes, we can talk about some postfix filter to handle the situation.

Comment: Actually, the site user can send anything which I have no control over it. Any header or email can be used.